# make node js game less laggy

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client

I have a node js game where I am using a function to generate a seek steering vector towards my player.
The problem is I am using set interval to constantly update this vector, as well as other data as my player moves around, client side. I'm looking at generating these vectors every interval for 100+ enemies.
Is there any way I could do this whole process better? I was thinking event based but I don't know what event the enemy Ai would react to, since the player position needs to be constantly updated for the server-side seek function to work.

```
            setInterval(function () {
                let seekList = [];
                let enemyIndices = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < amountOfEnemyLeaders; i++) {
                    let index = mainEnemies[i];
                    seekData = calculateSeek(lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies[Object.keys(lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies)[index]], players[socket.id]);
                    if (seekData !== undefined) {
                        lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies[Object.keys(lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies)[index]].sprite.x = seekData.movement.x * 10;
                        lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies[Object.keys(lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies)[index]].sprite.y = seekData.movement.y * 10;
                        seekList.push({x: lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies[Object.keys(lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies)[index]].sprite.x, y: lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies[Object.keys(lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies)[index]].sprite.y});
                        enemyIndices.push(mainEnemies[i]);
                    }
                }

                io.in(lobbyCode).emit('applyEnemyMovement', seekList, enemyIndices, lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies);
            }, 50);
```

Comment: one thing you can do is that move this line before the loop `Object.keys(lobbyObjs[lobbyCode].enemies)`

Comment: @aRvi Yep didn't catch that one. Thank you! There will still definitely be a problem with the lag though... would you recommend taking away set interval? I'm not really sure how I could update this constantly without lag, while being able to handle many users.

Comment: If I take away set interval it has to be event based. I'm not really sure how I'd do that because I want the enemies to constantly seek the player, and since this is a game where players will be moving around a lot, there really is no event other than the start of player movement, which won't help if the player constantly moves around.

Comment: you should consider using messaging queues, sockets

Comment: I'm already using socket.io. Should I change that?